# Javascript: how to get surrounded span class of selected text in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, select

example: `<div id="somewhat">one to three <span class="font-weight-bold">bold</span> four five </div>` 
I just want to select the word "bold" with doubleclick in Firefox. How can i get and change the classname of the surrounded span? With microsoft edge-chrome i have a solution.

Comment: Please show the code you have written so far.

Comment: here you can find my demo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160695/firefox-is-not-getting-surrounded-tagname-for-text-range

works fine with edge-chrome but firefox find the div instead of the span.

let tagName = sel.anchorNode.parentNode.tagName;